# Same User, multiple accounts with different roles

Tags: php, symfony

I'm creating an application in Symfony 3, that has the following structure:

```
class Account {
    private $id;
    private $name;
}

class User {
    private $id;
    private $email;
    private $password;
}

class UserAccount {
    private $id;
    private $userId;
    private $roles;
}
```

As we can see an user can belong to several accounts with different roles for each account, let's say that for Account 1 it has the role ROLE_ADMIN, and for the Account 2 it has the role ROLE_EDITOR.

The problem is that the user will have a select box where he can change the account, this means that the role needs to be loaded from the database based on a value on session ( since the account ID ) will be set on session.

This also means that when an user logins into the site, there will be no role, since the role is determined by the account selected.

I have tough about using events, but that doesn't seem to work from what I've read.

Does anyone has any thoughts/insights into this?

I have my own custom Authenticator, since I need to support both MD5 and bcrypt passwords.

This means that I have a class that extends SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface of Symfony, this allows me to have the users login with MD5 and automatically upgrade them to bcrypt.

My User model ( which is an normal one ), and Custom Authenticator: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/SDiniz/299a19977325adf7aa3eeac9a402e0b1)

To sumarize: I need a way in which I can change the roles of the user after he has logged in, without forcing the re login of the user.

Comment: man, you need inheritance so bad

Comment: also we need more information to make this a legitimate question, this is very general and will only give opinionated responses.

Comment: @iam-decoder what kind of information do you need?  Ask and I shall provide, I tought about inheritance, the account being an implementation of user, but that in my head still doesn't work.. since the roles still need to be changed after the login.

Comment: You said you have a "Custom Authenticator" how does it determine selected role? is it possible to leave that part out of the authenticator? Basically it's hard to tell whats stopping you from just updating the session to be the new role.

Comment: @iam-decoder, I've added more information above, but for now it uses the role determined in the User model, which is hard coded. Hope this helps, but thinking about it, I just need to change the role of the user based on a value of the session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after two days of struggle, here is the solution.

Looking at the question, when the user logins it needs to take a role determined by what is in the UserAccount table, since an user can have several accounts associated to him, the only way to solve this was to first create a post login listener:

```
 /**
  * On login
  * 
  * @param  InteractiveLoginEvent        $event The login event
  * 
  * @return void
  */
  public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event) {
       $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
       // get the user accounts of the current from the database
       $accountsOfUser = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\AccountHasUser')->getAccountsOfUser($user->getId());
       foreach ( $accountsOfUser as $accountOfUser ) {
            $this->session->set('accountid', $accountOfUser['account_id']);
                $user->resetAndAddRole('ROLE_' . $accountOfUser['const']);
                break;
       }
       // We just need to set the new security token
       $token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
            $user,
            null,
           'main',
           $user->getRoles()
      );
      // Update the current token to set the new role
      $this->tokenStorage->setToken($token);
}
```

I known that I can only get one record from the database, but this was just for show ( don't blindly copy/paste this to your code ).

So basically I get the first account of the user, get it's role, put the account id on the session ( still got to read a bit more about bags on Symfony sessions ), and procede to generate a new UsernamePasswordToken and adding it to the tokenStorage.

The $user->resetAndAddRole, is a function in my User Model, that has only the following:

```
/**
 * Resets current user roles and add's the new one
 * 
 * @param  string       $role       The role to add
 * 
 * @return AppBundle\Entity\User
 */
public function resetAndAddRole($role) {
    $this->roles = array($role);
    return $this;
}
```

Now I also need to allow the user to change between accounts when is logged in, so in a controller:

```
public function changeAccountAction(Request $request, $id) {
        $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $newAccountRole = $em->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\AccountHasUser')->getAccountModelByAccountIdANdUserId($id, $user->getId());
        $user->resetAndAddRole('ROLE_' . $newAccountRole['const']);
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
            $user,
            null,
            'main',
            $user->getRoles()
        );
        // Update the current token to set the new role
        $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
        $this->get('session')->set('accountid', $id);
        // $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        // $accountsList = $em->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\AccountHasUser')->getAccountsOfUser($user->getId());
        // We need to change the users roles right here and how to we do it?
        // We simply change the 

        return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('dashboard'));
    }
```

Basically, get the account that is passed by parameter, change the session value, so we can use this in our queries and every other code that requires the account id, and then create a new UsernamePasswordToken and *voilá* everything starts to work perfectly.

Later on I'm going to move the code on the controller to a service, which will also be passed to the post login listener, so that way I only have one play to make the changes to.

I really don't know if this is the right *way* to do this, but for now it seems to work.